# Jquery esc hide method not hiding the elements

Tags: jquery, dom, hide

I was making a light box gallery but this code doesn't hide the lightbox `div` which was supposed to be hidden when I press the *esc* key.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==27) {
        $("#lightbox").hide();
    }
});
```

I have my DOM elements like this:

```
<div id="lightbox">
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="imageholder">
            <img name="lightboximage" src="images/demo/940x340.gif" height="600" width="700" align="left" />
            <div id="description">
                <h1><a href="url/cyberkiller.nishchal">Nishchal Gautam</a></h1>
                <p>Description about the image</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have placed the script below these elements, am I missing something?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Loos like you have a malformed HTML .. Extra closing div.. Is that a typo??

Comment: no, i am not getting errors there, may be any minor carelessness?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the html, its just laid out badly

Comment: Seems to work here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FBTVs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **keypress** event instead of **keyup**..

```
$(document).on('keypress' , function(e) {
   var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

   if(code ==27){
      $("#lightbox").hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use e.which, as keycode is not supported on all browsers

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.which==27)
  {
    $("#lightbox").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it works fine in my firefox, when I press ESC, it hide.
are you using firefox? maybe it's not working in other browers.
you'd better to change it to this for the compatibility:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which || e.charCode;
    if(key==27)
        $("#lightbox").hide();
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Certain keys like enter, tab, arrow keys, Esc, etc... need to be captured with the keypress event so you are better off using the keypress event.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(key ==27){
        $("#lightbox").hide();
    }
});
```